Blazor cookie auth (Individual Accounts) used by multiple Blazor web apps (ASP.NET core hosted)
I am trying to make a simple demo with multiple projects:
Solution projects:

Identity (Blazor Web App with Individual Accounts and Server interactive render mode)
App1 (Blazor Web App with Server interactive render mode)
App2 (Blazor Web App with WebAssembly interactive render mode)
App2.Client

Identity project will serve as authentication server with cookie authentication and local accounts. No need for external auth providers.
App1 and App2 are examples of Blazor apps with different render modes that use Identity app for authentication. All three projects will be deployed as docker containers, under same domain (domain/auth, domain/app1 and domain/app2), where reverse proxy (nginx) will do the routing.
This question is not about containers / proxy, its about how to setup app1 and app2 to use authentication provided by identity app.
Is there some example / guidance how to achieve this? I know there is a Duende identity server that does what I want, but since this is a new project with no revenues, while asking for free license from them (<1m revenue condition), I did not receive any response.

My suggestion for this is not using the identity server, try some other projects like Azure Entra ID or Google Auth.
